# AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions No annotated classes found for specified

Tags: java, spring

A springMVC demo project of my friend, by `xml` and package `war`, run by tomcat, when open `http://localhost:9035/show` it show Error message:

```
09-Jul-2020 14:59:07.827 信息 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions No annotated classes found for specified class/package [classpath:config/spring-mvc.xml]
09-Jul-2020 14:59:08.260 信息 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'springServlet': initialization completed in 504 ms
09-Jul-2020 15:25:56.811 警告 [http-nio-9035-exec-8] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/show] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springServlet'
```

Demo project of my friend

Please ignore Chinese comments

[image: File tree structure]

web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">

    <display-name>SPRING-SSM</display-name>

    <!--项目欢迎页-->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- 指定spring核心配置文件 -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:config/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- 配置前端控制器 -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <!-- 指定配置文件位置和名称 如果不设置,默认找/WEB-INF/<servlet-name>-servlet.xml -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:config/spring-mvc.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- 解决乱码的过滤器 -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>utf-8</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


    <!-- Session 配置 -->
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

</web-app>
```

ShowView.java

```java
package com.yihao.controller;

import jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.tree.TryCatchBlockNode;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class ShowView {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/show")
    public String show(){
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();

        mv.addObject("msg","开始你的表演");
        mv.addObject("method", "showIndex");
        //mv.setViewName("show");
        return "showView";
    }
}
```

spring-mvc.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- 配置SpringMVC -->
    <!-- 1.开启SpringMVC注解模式 -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- 2.静态资源默认servlet配置 (1)加入对静态资源的处理：js,gif,png (2)允许使用"/"做整体映射 -->
    <!--<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />-->
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

    <!-- 3.定义视图解析器 -->
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
    <!-- 文件上传解析器 -->
    <bean id="multipartResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="utf-8"></property>
        <!-- 1024 * 1024 * 20 = 20M -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="20971520"></property>
        <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="20971520"></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- 4.扫描web相关的bean -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.yihao.controller" />
</beans>
```

Comment: You are loading XML not java based configuration, remove the `contextClass` from your web.xml